# Zurb Foundation: layout not responsive on an iPhone

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to get Foundation to be responsive on my iPhone's browsers. I've tried Safari and Chrome on my phone and both of them show the desktop layout.

On the desktop however, if I shrink the browser window I see the layout respond.

I even tried adding one of Zurb's sample templates and that still didn't work.

See here:
http://jsbin.com/okayop/3

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the following within the **head** element of your document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: i knew it :) but didn't know it